# Gcc - why are lambdas not stripped during release build

Tags: c++, lambda, linker, llvm-clang

I'm creating a `.component` bundle on MacOSX with xCode 7. I'm trying to get rid of all debugging symbols and library symbols for release configuration.
I set all suitable options in xCode (like `Strip Debug Symbols`, `Strip style` to `all symbols`, `symbols hidden by default` etc.)

Unfortunately there are still some symbols visible in compiled and linked `component` file.

So I use `strip -x -S mybundle.component` to remove them externally. And it almost work but not for `lambdas` callers. If any of method is using `lambda` expression, resulting binary has it names and all the callees and callers till `lambda` itself in linker "semi-obfuscated" style like `ZN18MyClassName8MetodNameEP9BSFirstParamP7SecondParamE3$_1`
So it looks like a linker issue?

As an example, some code:

```
class AClass {

   public:
       void methodCallingCallbackInTheEnd();
       std::function<void(C*, D*)> myCallback;
}

class BClass {

   AClass a;
   CClass *c;
   DClass *d;

   public:
       methodOfClassB() {  
          a->callback = [c,d] (C* c, D* d) {
              //do something with c and d objects
          };

          a->methodCallingCallbackInTheEnd();
       }
}

class EClass {
    public:
        EMethodNotVisibleInBinary();
}
```

So, as an effect of compiling and linking, I can see in binary some entries for A and B class, even with parameter types of C and D like that:

`ZN18AClass8callbackE34$_2`

then next some info about the callback itself, like:

`ZN18BClass8methodOfClassBEP9BSCClassP7DClassE3$_1`

Is there any way to get rid of them? Why they appear at all? `EClass`, `EMethodNotVisibleInBinary` etc. are not visible of course. There are no such strings in `.component` file.

It's very important to me and I don't want to obfuscate that parts of course.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please give a testcase that we can actually compile...

Comment: Why do you care? Are you worried that somebody is going to reverse engineer your code? The fully optimized build is not going to be easier to de-compile because of a few lambda symbols.

Comment: If you are building a dynamic library, you need *some* symbols.

Comment: Why do I care? Because those names are vital for my license management and they persist there. 
@MarcGlisse Cannot prepare test case - when trying to prepare such - it has no symbols at all with the same xCode settings for release.