# Visual C++ lambdas always output debug information

Tags: visual-c++

If I instantiate a lambda somewhere (and the compiler doesn't inline it), I can find a string showing where the lambda is located in my c++ code like this:

... `?AV<lambda_1>@?0??MyFunction@MyScopedClass@MyNamespace@@SAXXZ@` ...

I don't want this information in the executable, as it could give away important names of classes and functions.

All kinds of output debug information are turned off. If I use a normal function instead, the final executable doesn't have this information, so manually converting all lambdas into normal functions would "fix it". But what's the best way to handle this? Can we tell the compiler to transform lambdas into normal functions?

UPDATE: I tested with other compilers: g++ and clang. They both leave the same references. I also found another unanswered question about this [Gcc - why are lambdas not stripped during release build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796690/gcc-why-are-lambdas-not-stripped-during-release-build) Please don't come with the "why do you care about a few symbols anyway".

Here's some code you can test with:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class MyUnscopedClass
{
public:
    MyUnscopedClass(const std::function<void(int x)>& f) :
        f(f)
    {

    }
    std::function<void(int x)> f;
};

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyScopedClass
    {
    public:
        static void temp1(int x)
        {
            std::cout << x * (x + 1);
        }

        static void MyFunction()
        {
            //MyUnscopedClass obj(temp1); // no symbols
            MyUnscopedClass obj([](int x) // ?AV<lambda_1>@?0??MyFunction@MyScopedClass@MyNamespace@@SAXXZ@
                {
                    std::cout << x;
                });

            obj.f(23);
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    MyNamespace::MyScopedClass::MyFunction();
}
```

Comment: What version of VC++? The automatic lambda name is a mangled guid since at least VS [2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218665/change-compiler-generated-c-lambda-name-to-human-readable-one).

Comment: _MSC_VER is defined to 1927

Comment: That would be VS 2019 16.7 but it does not duplicate for me. Pasting your code into a default wizard generated C++ console app, the release mode EXE only contains `?AV<lambda_f65614ace4683bbc78b79ad57f781b7f>@@` in both x86 and x64 builds with VS 16.7.5.

Comment: That's strange. Maybe I tweaked some setting wrong in the compiler settings?

Comment: Quite strange, indeed. Not sure what setting that could be.

Comment: Wow! That's so weird. I found the setting. Configuration Properties > General > C++ Language Standard. Apparently the setting "Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (std:c++latest)" causes this issue

Comment: By the way, any idea what the identifier f65614ace4683bbc78b79ad57f781b7f means?

Comment: Funny, +1 if you post it as a self-answer. Don't know that the id has any particular significance, except probably being unique in some context.

Comment: It's sad that my code used some c++20 features like std::set::contains, so I will have to refactor :(

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @dxiv in the comments, I found the problematic setting.

`Configuration Properties > General > C++ Language Standard`

can't be, for some reason,

`Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (std:c++latest)`

So I set it to the second most recent one

`ISO C++17 Standard (std:c++17)`

and I get a random identifier instead.

`AV<lambda_f65614ace4683bbc78b79ad57f781b7f>@@`

I'm still curious how this identifier is chosen though.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this is intended behavior for whatever reasons, so I suggest you file an official report at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/62/index.html.

Comment: I did, let's see.